# Can't retrieve a value from the JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm passing values via PHP for this android java class(Login screen)but it's giving me a JSONException Error which I can't identify from the code below.
Could someone tell me how to fix kindly? thank you in advance!

**LoginActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputUid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUid);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String id = inputUid.getText().toString();
            String pswd = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(id, pswd);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in

                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json.getString(KEY_ID), json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                     

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: `No value for id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.addUser(json.getString(KEY_ID), json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
```

change to

```
db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_ID), json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
```